# how to create load more in react native for sections of inside flatlist

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

I get data from api like this :

```
let API_DATA = [{
 type:'type 1',
 detail:[{
  title:'...',
  pic:'...',
  time:'...'
 },{
  title:'...',
  pic:'...',
  time:'...'
 },{
  title:'...',
  pic:'...',
  time:'...'
 }] 
},{
 type:'type 2',
 detail:[{
  title:'...',
  pic:'...',
  time:'...'
 },{
  title:'...',
  pic:'...',
  time:'...'
 },{
  title:'...',
  pic:'...',
  time:'...'
 }] 
},{
 type:'type 3',
 detail:[{
  title:'...',
  pic:'...',
  time:'...'
 },{
  title:'...',
  pic:'...',
  time:'...'
 },{
  title:'...',
  pic:'...',
  time:'...'
 }] 
}]
```

For this I'm using 2 FlatList

```
<FlatList 
data={API_DATA}
rebderItem={(item)=>{

  <Text>item.type</Text>

  <FlatList 
  data={item.detail}
  rebderItem={(item)=>{
    <Text>item.title</Text>
    <Image source={uri:item.pic}/>
    <Text>item.time</Text>
  }}/>
}}/>
```

And other 3 section after these FlatLists

Now I want to create load more for each of these parts, and at first I want load 5 item from first part (type 1) section and with scroll load next 5 item, and after finish part 1 again with scroll load 5 item from part 2, Until the all data runs out, and after load API_DATA load another 3 section (this 3 section actually are 3 component)

Comment: Use `section list` instead of `Flatlist`. https://reactnative.dev/docs/sectionlist